# NextJS JSS on container missing Sitecore items

Tags: jss

I'm following this walk through to setup `NextJS JSS` on `container`
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--setting-up-a-development-environment-with-the-sitecore-containers-template-for-next-js.html

However, the script only seems to create items below:

[image]

**Questions**

1. Is above expected? If not how do I create all the required items (similar to netcore below)?

[image]

2. I manually copied the items from netcore rendering version but keep getting this error:

[image]

3. Even with `dotnetcore` as well I don't see `styleguide` or  `'graphql items`. I tried to perform `jss deploy items` and I keep getting 400. Not sure whether it should technically work on docker container instance.

[image]